# Why can't I add Google Cast Companion Library to my project?

Tags: android

Currently, my project uses the Cast Companion library from sources. Here are my dependencies in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('../../external/commonlibs/json/json-io-2.6.0.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: '../../external/commonlibs/annotations', include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'src/main/libs')
    compile project(':common')
    compile project(':common_ui')
    compile project(':android-google-play-services_lib-v22')
    compile project(':android-CastCompanionLibrary-v22')
    compile project(':adara-middleware')
    compile project(':android-support')
    compile project(':android-mediarouter')
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    testCompile fileTree(dir: '../../external/testlibs', include: '*.jar')

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
}
```

I want to remove the line "compile project(':android-CastCompanionLibrary-v22')" and replace it with:

```
compile 'com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary:ccl:2.9.1'
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'Fling'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_myCatapulTVeDebugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary:ccl:2.9.1.
     Required by:
         :Fling:unspecified
```

I am following the instructions from this link: https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android

Comment: did you do step two in the instructions? there may be dependencies that aren't being resolved because step two isn't done. From the instructions, it looks like your importing a project and linking it to the one you're trying to create

Comment: @ralphie9224 There is no step 2. Unless you mean option 2, which is again adding the library as a source, rather than a Jcenter repo. Option 2 is what is currently in place for my project.